# Two condition in one regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in php with these condition:

```
 1. Two letters, then six numbers (ha123456).

 2. Or one letter, then seven numbers (j0123456).
```

Now I have this, but it doesn`t work properly.

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{6,7}
```

Any suggestion ? or do i have to check it with function ?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{7}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6})\b`? `^(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{7}|[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6})$`? `\b(?=\w{8}\b)[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{6,7}\b`?

Comment: Try yo rephrase the requirement as: one letter followed by one letter or digit followed by six digits. Can you write the regex now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```regex
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9][0-9]{6}$
```

This meets both expected inputs, because they both start with a single letter, and end in 6 digits.  The only difference is the second character, which can be either a letter or a digit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Good one (+1). Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lytPZ3/1

Answer (score 1):

There's other ways of doing this but I always like the straight forward regex style of:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6})|([a-zA-Z][0-9]{7})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XgVXvX/1)

It has 2 letters + 6 numbers OR 1 letter and 7 numbers.